# How to make a space between DIV in bootstrap 4 modal?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How to make a space between DIV in bootstrap 4 modal?

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="form-group clearfix row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 pd-30 card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pd-30 card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pd-30 card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pd-30 card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">4</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does adding some padding-right to 1,2,3 do the trick? edit: add this Ex: style="padding-right: 10px"

Comment: Can add `mr-1` (up to 5) [Bootstrap Spacing](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a `div` and put all `classes name` in that div. don't use everything with `col-`.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class=" more classes here">
     .....
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group clearfix row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pd-30">
      <div class=" card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">1</h1>
      </div>
        
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pd-30">
      <div class=" card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">1</h1>
      </div>
        
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pd-30">
      <div class=" card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">1</h1>
      </div>
        
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pd-30">
      <div class=" card bg-info border-radius-5 box-shadow text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-white">1</h1>
      </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```